# Link error for a 3rd party library with my ios application

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an existing iOS application which uses a 3rd party static library (something like libThirdParty.a). In a new release of the library, I am getting link errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::at(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      boost::posix_time::time_duration boost::date_time::parse_undelimited_time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libThirdParty.a(SomeClass.cpp.obj)
      boost::posix_time::time_duration boost::date_time::parse_undelimited_time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libThirdParty.a(SomeClass.cpp.obj)
      boost::posix_time::time_duration boost::date_time::parse_undelimited_time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libThirdParty.a(SomeClass.cpp.obj)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::copy(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const",
```

The application and library are both compiled for amrv7 and arm64. I confirmed this by

```
what libThirdParty.a
```

I am guessing that this is missing some library dependancy, or that the 3rd party library was compiled using standard library different from what I am using. Is this assumption right, and how can I identify what is missing?

Comment: are you using pods for your library?

Comment: @iRaju Not using pods

Comment: Check presence of libstdc++ lib in your "Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries"...

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan  That worked!! Thanks. I still dont know why that happened, I could see the link command already had -llibstd even before your suggestion. With your suggestion, libstd was linked after the 3rd party library. Guess the order mattered in some wierd way

Comment: @jogabonito oh, thats cool, congrats )